# How do I plot a power function 1-\phi(4.65-x/2) in R?

Tags: r

I want to plot a [power function][1] in R, namely 1-\phi(4.65-z/2). This can be written as \int_{-\infty}^{4.65-z/2}\frac{1}{2\pi} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2}}) in latex.

Can someone explain how to plot this?  Is there a specific command for the phi function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function, \Phi, is a cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable, and yes, there is a function for that in R: `dnorm`. Hence,

```
z <- seq(-2, 20, length = 1000)
plot(z, 1 - dnorm(4.65 - z / 2), type = 'l')
# or also just curve(1 - dnorm(4.65 - x / 2), -2, 20)
```

[image]